# How to fix "div" tag between </li> <li> tags

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to order some lines created with li tag using Dreamweaver. clear: both does the job well and looks fine in Dreamweaver. But when I validate the code I'm getting some errors similar to these:

```
Line 65, Column 53: document type does not allow element "div" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag
<div style="clear: both; background: none; "></div>
Line 73, Column 12: document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag
<li>
```

My code is here: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/90799/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `div` there is semantically incorrect.

The `ul` and `ol` elements can only have `li`'s as children nodes.  The `li`'s may have other types of elements though.

The CSS pseudo-selector `:after` should do the trick for you here.

Or you can use another variation of it, but I think it is what fits the bill for what you're asking.

Try this: 
`li:after {clear: both; }`

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip. All problems suddenly gone applying this selector. And thanks to knichol that I learned it isn't compatible with ie6 and ie7. so I'll just put a warning for visitors about their browser version.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the `style="clear:both;"` to the `<li>` and remove the offending `<div>` all together.

I do not advise using the CSS `li:after {}` simply because that selector is not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i had tried it but it didn't seem fine with dreamweaver. so i asked here.

Answer (score 0):

`div` needs to be inside an `li` tag if its gonna be a child of the `ul` tag

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<li>` is an inline element and `<div>` is a block element.

**block**: an element which forms a separate block.

**inline**: an element which stays inline with the rest of the content.

Therefore theoretically, there cannot exist a block element inside an inline element. But only theoretically because in practice browsers interpret this as normal.

Tip: do not worry about the W3C validation!